# Why is my PHP code overriding my HTML code?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, cpanel

I'm using bootstrap to make a website and I noticed my php index overrides my html index. Is the php code supposed to refer part of the html code to display?

For example, I have a nice little text message that says "*hey*" in html. Then some random php password checker script I found online.

Nothing in my page says "*hey*", it's as if the php is the html. I'm new so maybe I'm just tripping.

Sorry if it is hard to understand.

Comment: It sounds like you have two `index` pages; `index.html` and `index.php`. Yes, the PHP page will take precedence. But you can still write HTML from within the PHP file.

Comment: Hi Lord, PHP is interpreted and executed server-side, HTML instead client-side (by the browser).
A good reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have two `index` pages: `index.html` and `index.php`.

The PHP page will take precedence due to the [DirectoryIndex directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html) of Apache:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

You can change this to pick `.html` files by default if you would like (by swapping the order so that `index.html` comes first), though there is no real need, as you can still write HTML from within the PHP file:

`index.php`:

```
<?php
echo "<h1>hey</h1>";
?>

<h1>hey</h1>
```

Both approaches are valid, and both will allow you to output HTML from a PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an Apache server? If so, there is a directive in there that tells it what to do when you reference a folder and not a file. It will list the file types in order of priority. For example:

`DirectoryIndex index.php index.html`

Swap `index.php` and `index.html` around and the HTML will take priority.

You can find the directive in your Apache config file usually called *httpd.conf* or *apache.conf*.

Alternatively, to make sure the correct file is called, just reference it explicitly in your browser eg: `localhost/index.html`.